# Lenovo S60 Bootloader Damaged

Tags: lenovo

My phone (Lenovo s60) got off while I was restoring it, and now I can’t even turn it on. Only a red light is flashing when connected to charger and it can’t be connected to computer, there are no drivers matching to connect the device with pc, later I found a driver named Qualcomm to connect the device and it connect the device with the computer but I can’t do anything else.
 Please help me to restore my device

Comment: You'll find most people won't bother to strain their eyes trying to read a question that's all-caps. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method. This is the convectional way of installing/upgrading firmware on most android devices:

- Download official firmware (correct version) preferably on PC. Extract the download you should see a **sdfuse folder**

Depending on contents of the compressed file you may not find the sdfuse folder, in this case;

- create a folder in your external sdcard and rename it as sdfuse
- extract firmware zip and copy qsb firmware "the file vit extension .qsb" to sdfuse folder or it may have the .inb extension.

  - You will need to transfer **sdfuse folder** preferably using a micro sd card Adapter or card reader from the PC  to the phone.
  - Make sure phone is off completely. Then press and HOLD the POWER+VOLUME DOWN buttons simultaneously until the **service menu** appears.
  - Using your Vol+/Vol- buttons navigate to **sd update** and the installation should begin. Follow the instructions carefully to successfully re-install the firmware.

(*Your phone must have at least 50-80% of battery charged* )

Credits:

1. [Lenovo S60-A Flash File (Stock ROM) zip](http://supergeekforum.org/lenovo-s60-a-flash-file-stock-rom-zip)